# WordPress Adding an Extra Tag to enqueue

Tags: wordpress

```
function twentytwelve_add_lightbox() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/js/jlightbox.js', array( 'fancybox' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/css/fancybox.css' );
}   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_add_lightbox' );
```

This should enqueue the css as is, but I am getting an error when loading the page.
enqueue. `http://localhost:8888/ramova2/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/inc/lightbox/css/fancybox.css?ver=4.0.1` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) because wordpress adds a ?ver=4.0.1 tag at the end of the link.

Comment: CSS versioning shouldn't cause that kind of trouble. Did you triple check the path and file name? Are you using a child theme, or are you modifying twentytwelve directly?

Comment: if you open the file in question, does it show anything?